# Overflowing button text is being clipped in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a simple button tag and I specifically want the text to overflow the button. 
This works fine in current browsers with the exception of Safari (ios and osx) which clips the text at the button boundary.

```css
button,
.button {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: 'clip';
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    border: none
}
```

```html
<button>Very long text Very long text Very long text This Clips In Safari</button>
<div class='button'>Very long text Very long text Very long text This Overflows</div>
```

I can't figure out how to get the text to overflow. 
Does anyone know how to make this work.
TIA

Answer (score 21):

So eventually I found a work around.

If I wrap the text in a span and then set the span to position:relative the overflowing text will display correctly without being clipped.

Also note the recommendation above to use text-overflow:clip is wrong, has no impact on this and text-overflow:'' is valid.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for posting. *Sigh, Safari....why do people use it? :P

Comment: so it's clear, the answer is to set the element that is being clipped to `position:relative` and it will no longer happen.